# Perl EMAIL Dependencies

Tags: perl, email, dependencies

I am trying to use test perl's email using the example listed from
http://learn.perl.org/examples/email.html. I am running this on Windows 7.
For some reason, Email::Sender::Simple is referencing other modules that are not loaded when Email::Sender is loaded.

How can one load these modules so that all dependencies get loaded without searching in each module for all referenced packages? Currently I am using ActiveState and ppm install.

```
use 5.14.2;
use strict;
use warnings;

# first, create your message
use Email::MIME;
my $message = Email::MIME->create(
  header_str => [
    From    => 'you@example.com',
    To      => 'friend@example.com',
    Subject => 'Happy birthday!',
  ],
  attributes => {
    encoding => 'quoted-printable',
    charset  => 'ISO-8859-1',
  },
  body_str => "Happy birthday to you!\n",
);

# send the message
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
sendmail($message);
```

Of course, I could dump the %INC but the output includes a ton of modules.
Ideally, I would like to load Email::MIME and Email::Sender::Simple and have this work.

Comment: Of all Perl modules to send email that I tried over the years, I like `Mail::Sender` best. On Windows ActivePerl, you can install it by `ppm install Mail::Sender`.

Comment: The documentation lacks a simple example. Do you have a link to an example that allows me to send an email from my client through my ISP's smtp server? Perl's website example looks easy but it will not compile due to a multitude of missing modules.

Comment: ok, I have added an answer with working example for you

Comment: My ISP is "wowway".  So for smtp, I used your example and set it equal to "smtp.mail.wowway.com". While the program runs, my mail box shows no emails. I did use valid username, password and email addresses. Adding :587 would only cause the program to complain. Now I am communicating with my ISP. I do not have an smtp server on my laptop. Is this the problem? I must be missing an important point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [`Mail::Sender`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mail%3a%3aSender), you can install it in ActivePerl using `ppm install Mail::Sender`, in Linux install it with

```
sudo apt-get install libmail-sender-perl
```

This module is very versatile, supports multiple attachments, inlining, SMTP password authentication (even including NTLM - necessary to talk to Exchange servers).

This is an example to send HTML mail using `Mail::Sender`:

```
use Mail::Sender;

my $sender = new Mail::Sender({
    # provider may require using port 587:
    smtp    => "smtp.example.com",
    # auth parameters below are optional
    # and depend on provider requirements
    auth    => "LOGIN",
    authid  => $username,
    authpwd => $password,
    from    => "myself@example.com",
});

$sender->Open({
    to       => "recipient@example.com",
    cc       => "anotherguy@example.com",
    subject  => "Subject line",
    ctype    => "text/html",
    encoding => "7bit",
}) or die ($Mail::Sender::Error, "\n");

my $html = "<html><body>Test HTML content</body></html>";

$sender->SendEx($html)
    or die ($Mail::Sender::Error, "\n");
$sender->Close();

print "Test message has been sent\n";
```

Comment: My ISP is "wowway". So for smtp, I used your example and set it equal to "smtp.mail.wowway.com". While the program runs, my mail box shows no emails. I did use valid username, password and email addresses. Adding :587 would only cause the program to complain. Now I am communicating with my ISP. I do not have an smtp server on my laptop. Is this the problem? I must be missing an important point. – sammy 6 mins ago

Comment: If your provider allows to send email over std port 25, then you can use just hostname. Some providers like Comcast require using submission port 587. It seems like your provider supports both schemes. Also try adding `auth => "LOGIN"` - this is the only auth scheme your provider supports. I have edited my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

*Email::Sender::Simple* and just *Email::Sender* are two different modules, so you have to do this:

From cmd:

```
C:\>cpan
C:\>install Email::Sender::Simple
```

That's all.